# How to create mock object of main class to have partial integration test using PlaySpec?

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, integration-testing

There is a main class named 'MainProcess.scala' that I'm running some test cases for it. I wanno write an end to end test for this class to validate it's functionality. 
Th problem here is the end to end test requires some criteria has to be established to be able to test whole functionality. For instance:

```
class MainProcess() {
    def foo(someparams):Future[Boolean] = {
         if criteria true else false
     }
   def bee(some params):Future[WSResponse] = {
       //  call a micro service 
       }
}
```

My question is: Is it a good practice to mock 'foo' method such that it always return true or mock 'bee' method so that test can pass through these modules and continue till it reaches the point I intend to see it's result. As I am testing this class, I know that  mocking the same class results into error or malfunctionality of test case:

```
private def guiceApplicationBuilder(app: Application): Application = {
new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .overrides(bind[MainProcess].toInstance(mainProcessMock))
  .build()
```

}

If this is not a good practice, so how to do such stuff to mock specific modules of main class?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is is an integration test or a unit test ?

Comment: It is an integration test. To test whole class functionality I need to mock output of some modules lies in between to let tests go through other parts of the code.

Comment: If it is an end 2 end test adding mocks inside the app seems odd, where is that condition coming from?